# Cloning a list inside a function Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def foo(image):
    res = image[:]
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            res[i][j] = 1
    return image

foo([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
```

For the above function, I copied the image to res and only modified res inside the function. So I assumed that calling the function should return the same as my input. However, the output is a 3 by 3 arrays with all ones. Could anyone explain this to me, please? Thanks.

I guess it is something related to local and global variables, but I am not sure. If I want to clone the image to res and only change the values for res, how am I supposed to manage it?

Comment: "I copied the image to res and only modified res inside the function. So I assumed that calling the function should return the same as my input" that is simply an invalid inference. You created a new, shallow copy and returned it.

Comment: Note, the modifications you made to the inner lists will affect the original list you passed in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You're seeing this behaviour because `res` is a shallow copy of `image`.

To see the behaviour you expected you will need to create a deep copy instead, luckily the standard library includes a way to do this for simple cases.

```python
import copy

def foo(image):
    res = copy.deepcopy(image)
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            res[i][j] = 1
    return image

foo([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
```

If you don't want to bring in another dependency, then you can get the same result with a list comprehension.

```py
def foo(image):
    res = [x[:] for x in image]
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            res[i][j] = 1
    return image

foo([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
```

## Explanation

Lists in python are by reference, not value, the same list can be accessed by different names.

We can see this by running the following:

```py
import copy

original = [[1]]
shallow_copy = original[:]
deep_copy = copy.deepcopy(original)

shallow_copy[0][0] = 2

print(original)
print(deep_copy)
```

When you copy a list with `image[:]`, python does the following:

1. Creates a new list.
2. For every item in `image`, add *the same item* to the new list.

**It does not *copy* the internal lists, it just points to the original one.**

As a result `original` and `shallow_copy` are different lists, but `original[0]` and `shallow_copy[0]` are the same list.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `res = image[:]` creates a shallow copy of the `res` list. The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists, dicts, sets or class instances):

- A **shallow copy** constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
- A **deep copy** constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

So, in your code both `res` and `image` contain references to the same list objects.

[[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#:%7E:text=A%20shallow%20copy%20constructs%20a,objects%20found%20in%20the%20original.)]